# Cannot boot into Windows after installing server 9.04

Tags: boot, windows

I was installing Ubuntu server 9.04 on my laptop running on Windows 7 x64. I installed it from CD and I'm not very sure about how the partitioning system as shown on the setup. I'm not very sure which one I pick and then, after the setup run successfully, I can't boot into Windows. And when I put the Windows installation disk, it can't even recognize the type of my disk. It even said it's not an NTFS file system.

My question is, is my data still in there and is there anyway I can retrieve it back?
And, does that mean my disk have been converted to ext2 format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like you've installed over Windows.
If your laptop has an HDD instead of SSD than the data is still there on one of the layers of the HDD. I would recommend not to put any more data on it and preferably to use a special service to recover data.
You can try to recover data yourself but you need an external HDD(USB External HDD) on which you would recover the data and also you would have to install recovery tools or use a data recovery CD.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like you formatted your drive with an `ext*` filesystem, which means your Windows data is no longer recoverable. If you installed alongside Windows, then there may be some hope. In order to confirm this, could you please install Gparted and post a screenshot of what your drive looks like.

To install GParted:

- Open a terminal by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T`
- type `sudo apt-get install gparted`
- You will be prompted for your password (to your computer)

Run Gparted, select your drive, take a screenshot, and post, and we can give you a more accurate answer.